# Moving interfaces but not concrete classes

Tags: object-oriented, architecture, interfaces, class-design, code-reuse

Recently I started working on creating a client library. One problem which I am facing now is that I have to move the below interface `Attributes` to client library but the concrete classes (business logic) should remain in the original library. The problem here is that the method signatures of the below interface are Concrete classes.

```
   public interface Attributes {

      public Integer getAttribute(IntegerAttr attr);

      public Boolean getAttribute(BooleanAttr attr);

      public String getAttribute(StringAttr attr);

      // some more code.
  }
```

Each of the above parameter classes implement one common interface called `Attr`.

```
class IntegerAttr implements Attr { .. }
class BooleanAttr implements Attr { .. }
...
```

Now if I try to make the parameters to type `Attr` in interface `Attributes` then we will get Override exception because of same method signature.

But I have to move this interface to client library but not the concrete classes.

Any suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it would be easier to answer if you had told us what you are really trying to accomplish (for example, why you are going to move the interface), but anywhere.

A straightforward approach works as follows:

1. Create interfaces `IIntegerAttr`, `IBooleanAttr` and `IStringAttr`, all derived from `Attr`.
2. Make `IntegerAttr` derive from `IIntegerAttr` (and the other two analogously).
3. Change the signature of the `getAttribute` methods to use the new interfaces.

Now you can move `Attributes` as well as the new interfaces to the client library, without having to move the concrete classes `IntegerAttr`, ....

Comment: Hmm. thought the same. Seems like there is only one way to solve this.